# Running GluonCV object detection model on Android

Tags: mxnet, mxnet-gluon

I need to run a custom GluonCV object detection module on Android.

I already fine-tuned the model (ssd_512_mobilenet1.0_custom) on a custom dataset, I tried running inference with it (loading the .params file produced during the training) and everything works perfectly on my computer. Now, I need to export this to Android.

I was referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607927/using-gluoncv-models-in-tensorflow-lite) to figure out the procedure, there are 3 suggested options:

1. You can use ONNX to convert models to other runtimes, for example [...] [NNAPI](https://github.com/JDAI-CV/DNNLibrary) for Android
2. You can use [TVM](https://docs.tvm.ai/deploy/android.html)
3. You can use SageMaker Neo + [DLR runtime](https://github.com/neo-ai/neo-ai-dlr) [...]

Regarding the first one, I converted my model to ONNX.
However, in order to use it with NNAPI, it is necessary to convert it to daq. In the repository, they provide a precomplied AppImage of onnx2daq to make the conversion, but the script returns an error. I checked the issues section, and [they report](https://github.com/JDAI-CV/DNNLibrary/issues/64) that "It actually fails for all onnx object detection models".

Then, I gave a try to DLR, since it's suggested to be the easiest way.
As I understand, in order to use my custom model with DLR, I would first need to compile it with TVM (which also covers the second point mentioned in the linked post). In the repo, they provide a Docker image with some conversion scripts for different frameworks.
I modified the 'compile_gluoncv.py' script, and now I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tvm import relay
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet.gluon.model_zoo.vision import get_model
from tvm_compiler_utils import tvm_compile

shape_dict = {'data': (1, 3, 300, 300)}
dtype='float32'
ctx = [mx.cpu(0)]

classes_custom = ["CML_mug"]
block = get_model('ssd_512_mobilenet1.0_custom', classes=classes_custom, pretrained_base=False, ctx=ctx)
block.load_parameters("ep_035.params", ctx=ctx) ### this is the file produced by training on the custom dataset


for arch in ["arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "x86"]:
  sym, params = relay.frontend.from_mxnet(block, shape=shape_dict, dtype=dtype)
  func = sym["main"]
  func = relay.Function(func.params, relay.nn.softmax(func.body), None, func.type_params, func.attrs)
  tvm_compile(func, params, arch, dlr_model_name)
```

However, when I run the script it returns the error:

```
ValueError: Model ssd_512_mobilenet1.0_custom is not supported. Available options are
    alexnet
    densenet121
    densenet161
    densenet169
    densenet201
    inceptionv3
    mobilenet0.25
    mobilenet0.5
    mobilenet0.75
    mobilenet1.0
    mobilenetv2_0.25
    mobilenetv2_0.5
    mobilenetv2_0.75
    mobilenetv2_1.0
    resnet101_v1
    resnet101_v2
    resnet152_v1
    resnet152_v2
    resnet18_v1
    resnet18_v2
    resnet34_v1
    resnet34_v2
    resnet50_v1
    resnet50_v2
    squeezenet1.0
    squeezenet1.1
    vgg11
    vgg11_bn
    vgg13
    vgg13_bn
    vgg16
    vgg16_bn
    vgg19
    vgg19_bn
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this thing even possible?

As a side note, after this I'd need to deploy on Android a pose detection model (simple_pose_resnet18_v1b) and an activity recognition one (i3d_nl10_resnet101_v1_kinetics400) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can run GluonCV model directly on Android with [Deep Java Library (DJL)](https://djl.ai)
What you need to do is:

1. [hyridize your GluonCV model and save as MXNet model](http://docs.djl.ai/docs/mxnet/how_to_convert_your_model_to_symbol.html)
2. Build MXNet engine for android, MXNET already support [Android](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/01387a20c3e54ce859e3849d541d51cf4b428358/ci/docker/runtime_functions.sh#L217-L256) build
3. Include MXNet shared library into your android project
4. Use DJL in your android project, you can follow this [DJL Android demo for PyTorch](https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo/tree/master/android)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! It seems this is precisely what I need, since  - as I understand - it allows to convert directly models from the GluonCV model ZOO. However, could you please elaborate a little bit on the procedure you described?
I used the link you provided (point 2), and ran './build.py -p armv7', which built a docker image on my computer with ( I guess) an MXNet installation compatible with Android. Should I...export it somehow, and use it in the Android project as you suggested in point 3? I checked the Android tutorial, but it doesn't provide much explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory - there is no model "**ssd_512_mobilenet1.0_custom**" supported by `mxnet.gluon.model_zoo.vision.get_model`. You are confusing GluonCV's `get_model` with MXNet Gluon's `get_model`.

Replace

```py
block = get_model('ssd_512_mobilenet1.0_custom',
    classes=classes_custom, pretrained_base=False, ctx=ctx)
```

with

```py
import gluoncv
block = gluoncv.model_zoo.get_model('ssd_512_mobilenet1.0_custom',
    classes=classes_custom, pretrained_base=False, ctx=ctx)
```